# Is it possible to execute copy/paste operations using Blender interface?

Tags: export

this may be a weird question. I started rendering my animation on my school computer and I left it overnight. How forgetful I was! I set the rendered images to save to the tmp folder not the folder I created. So now when I go to the 'output' section on the render tab and clicked on the folder icon next to it, I see all my rendered pngs but the thing is that I can't drag all the pngs to the folder that I created. I also can't access the tmp folder on the windows computer manually itself as I don't have an administrator password. So I'm wondering is there a way to drag all the rendered pngs out from Blender program itself to the folder I created? 
[image]

The 'output' section on Blender I know it does say 'tmp' now that is because I'm now starting to render again.

[image]

Rendered PNGs

Comment: Is your question about copying files using Blender interface?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: @root can you write this as an answer?

Comment: @Georges It's the wrong answer.

Comment: @root it doesn't work?

Comment: @Georges It does but it's not what OP is asking. feel free to write it as an answer if you want

Comment: @root You're right, it can help him in this situation though

Comment: Before you do anything else you should contact the administrators for the system you are using. First of all you don't want to loose your content and I'm sure they would help you preventing any accidental deletion. Second of all if you do find a workaround they would need to know about it as it would mean a security issue to the system...

Comment: @cegaton The reason why I'm asking is because IT is too busy today fixing things and no students are allowed to go to IT. I had already started the rendering process again. I'll delete this question if  you want me to.

Comment: @JeffTeoh please don't delete your questions! Others might find them useful.

Comment: @cegaton Alright then

Comment: If the file is protected by windows, presumably it will stop programs from entering there, otherwise it would be way to easy to bypass the protection password, so just of a guess, it may not be possible. (I'm no expert though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender can't copy and/or move files.

One way of doing it though is to open the files as a image sequence using the video sequence editor.

Press Add->Image

[image]

Select all the images of your Render and add them to the editor.

You can press "b" for box select to make it easier.

[image]

If you now use the same render output setting (except fo the output path)
You can animate this and get your images saved in another folder.

How this works:

Blender opens up the file from the path you saved your animation in. You should be able to read it.

By adding a image sequence in the video editor it overlaps the current scene and does not render it. Your images get saved to a different folder.